# Running CUPS next to Apache2 Webserver

Tags: apache2, cups

I've been running an Apache2 server for a while. I just installed CUPS when I realized that these two services are always blocking each other. (Obviously because CUPS comes with a webserver)

My question is, how can I run both services properly?

Thanks,
UncleCuppa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found about that issue. It's simple as:
Just make sure your /etc/apache2/port.conf doesn't list Port 631.

That should fix the error